# Move data via macro

Tags: vba, excel, csv

OK first off, all the data is originally in a xlsm file. A macro runs (via task scheduled)and make the tabs into csv file. Work perfectly.

Second I have a website that reads the data, and displays it in a graph. The javascript that i used to make this work, reads the data from columns. works perfectly.

Now for the problem... The csv files that are exported via the macro, don't read properly. this is due to the first and last lines of data. first line i don't need, however i can use the last line.

So here i want i ask... 
1. how do i remove the first row
2. is there a way i can move the row into the next column.

This is what it looks like now.

```
Auto+Hide   Fit     Fit       Fit
           No.      Name    Comm MTD
          E00043    Julie      2
          E00143    Jodie      1
          E00198    Jason      0
          E00289    Ronald     0
          E00345    Patimah    2
          E00356    Jenny      1
          TARGET               6
```

I would like it to look like this.

```
    No.     Name   Comm MTD  TARGET
    E001    Julie      2        6
    E002    Jodie      1
    E003    Jason      0
    E004    Ronald     0
    E005    Patimah    2
    E006    Jenny      1
```

I don't want to manually edit the data if possible, as this process is meant to be automated.

Any help would be appreciate

**UPDATE**

This is my current code.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("page 1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\weburl.com.au\data\page 1.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("page 2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\weburl.com.au\data\page 2.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("page 3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\weburl.com.au\data\page 3.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("page 4").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\weburl.com.au\data\page 4.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
   'ActiveWorkbook.Saved = False
   'Application.Quit
End Sub
```

So how can i add a delete row command into it.

Sorry i don't know this language very well.

Comment: showing the macro might help. Alternatively, just delete the first row after the export is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this right after "Application.ScreenUpdating=false"

```
For pageNumber = 1 To 4
    Sheets("page " & pageNumber).Rows(1).Delete
    Sheets("page " & pageNumber).Columns(1).Delete
    Sheets("page " & pageNumber).Range("D1").Value = "TARGET"
    Sheets("page " & pageNumber).Range("D2").Formula = "=SUM(C2:C6)"
    Sheets("page " & pageNumber).Range("D2").Calculate
    Sheets("page " & pageNumber).Range("D2").Value = Sheets("page " & pageNumber).Range("D2").Value
Next pageNumber
```

again, Without knowing any more about your setup, some ranges might have to be modified.

though this might have to be tweaked to adapt to variably sized data.

also just to be safe, sometimes when I am exporting data I like to do a sort of inline copy-paste to convert formula data to value data
Range("D2").Value=Range("D2").Value

this replaces the contents of the cell (a formula) with the raw value.

Comment: As simply as this code is, i can't get it to work for me. As i said I'm not very good with this language. I have update the original post with the macro used to output the csv files. if you could tell me how i'm meant to add the delete function, i would be very grateful.

Comment: are you trying to do this on all 4 sheets, or just one of them? you said that you could not get the code to work, could you post the version of the macro where you inserted my code? that would make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: Thats the thing i don't know were the code needs to go. so i have been place the code in and trying it. and yes i need this for all 4 sheets. as i look at it if i can remove from one, i can remove from all...yes.